# Twilio Post Issue on Heroku + Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, dns, twilio

My app used to be hosted on another hosting platform but I've had to move it to Heroku recently.

Since the DNS is hosted with GoDaddy, I've had to CNAME www.medapulse.org to https://salty-coast-5328.herokuapp.com/ and then forward medapulse.org to www.medapulse.org.Sending texts from the app works perfectly fine so the Twilio setup is corre

Sadly, this has broken my route for the app to receive text messages (to convert into emails and save to the db).

This is the current route that was working with medapulse.org:

```
get "text_messages/receive"
match '/receivetext' =>    'text_messages#receive', :via => :post
```

I've tried to change the Twilio POST URL to no avail when I text the app:

POST URLs I've tried on Twilio:

- http://medapulse.org/receivetext (408 response)
- http://www.medapulse.org/receivetext (400 response)
- http://salty-coast-5328.herokuapp.com/receivetext (404 response)
- https://salty-coast-5328.herokuapp.com/receivetext (500 response)

I'm sure this is related to forwarding the URL/understand posting to Heroku. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is solved.

I kept the /receivetext route and am posting to:

https://salty-coast-5328.herokuapp.com/receivetext

Hope this helps someone else who has migrated to Heroku.